# Async Task implementation

Tags: c#, .net

Beeing on .NET 3.5 i don't have access to the TPL. Yet i have become fed up of having to manage manually the logic behind delegate.BeginInvoke type of scenarios each time and i set up to implement my own Task class.

Functionality it should support:

- starting a parallel  execution (using
  a thread pool thread)
- capable of Waiting on the result with a specific timeout
- capable of aborting said execution
- should provide event for callbacks to attach to

This is my implementation. Can you guys please review it and specify if there are any issues i might not have considered or maybe more effective ways to implement some things?

```
public class Task<T>
{
    #region Members
    private IAsyncResult _async;
    private Func<T> _action;
    private Func<T> _innerAction;
    private WaitHandle _waitHandle;
    private Thread _thread;
    private object _completedLock = new object();
    private object _abortLock = new object();
    private T _result;
    private bool _endCalled = false;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public object Tag { get; private set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public T Result
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_endCalled)
            {
                lock (_completedLock)
                {
                    if (!_endCalled)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (_async != null)
                            {
                                _result = _innerAction.EndInvoke(_async);
                                IsCompleted = true;
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            _endCalled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return _result;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event EventHandler Completed;
    #endregion

    public Task(Func<T> action, object tag)
        : this(action)
    {
        Tag = tag;
    }

    public Task(Func<T> action)
    {
        _action = action;
        _innerAction = () =>
        {
            try
            {
                _thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
                var result = _action();
                return result;
            }
            finally
            {
                lock (_abortLock)
                {
                    IsRunning = false;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    #region Public Methods
    public void Run()
    {
        if (!IsRunning || IsCompleted)
        {
            lock (_completedLock)
            {
                if (!IsRunning || IsCompleted)
                {
                    ResetState();
                    _async = _innerAction.BeginInvoke(obj => OnCompleted(), null);
                    IsRunning = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Task is already running");
    }

    public bool WaitForCompletion(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        if (IsRunning && !IsCompleted)
        {
            lock (_completedLock)
            {
                if (!IsCompleted)
                {
                    _waitHandle = _async.AsyncWaitHandle;
                    return _waitHandle.WaitOne(timeout);
                }
            }
        }
        return IsCompleted;
    }

    public bool WaitForCompletion(int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        return WaitForCompletion(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds));
    }

    public bool Abort()
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (!IsCompleted)
        {
            lock (_abortLock)
            {
                if (!IsCompleted && IsRunning)
                {
                    if (_thread != null)
                    {
                        _thread.Abort();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
                ResetState();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    #endregion

    private void ResetState()
    {
        _async = null;
        _endCalled = false;
        _result = default(T);
        _thread = null;
        IsCompleted = false;
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        lock (_completedLock)
        {
            IsCompleted = true;
            if (_waitHandle != null)
            {
                _waitHandle.Close();
                _waitHandle = null;
            }
        }

        if (Completed != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            catch
            {
                //We swallow this as there is no way to catch it at an upper level
                //on the execution thread and do something about it.
                //Callbacks should not throw anyway.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You may want to consider replacing the flags (`IsRunning`/`IsCompleted`) with a single state enum.
- Some state checks use `_abortLock` while others use `_completedLock`.

  1. If `Abort()` is called on a Task that has not started,
  2. a context switch happens just before `ResetState()` is called,
  3. a second thread calls `Run()` and the new inner thread starts,
  4. another context switch happens and the first thread resumes to call `ResetState()`

  Yeah, a few moons would need to be in alignment for this to happen ... but still.
- If `Run()` is called followed by `Abort()` before the inner thread actually starts, then _thread could be null resulting the thread not actually being aborted and inconsistent state. (again with the moons.)
- Abort will not terminate the thread immediately, you should wait for it to complete before resetting the state.
- I'm not sure aborting a thread pool thread is a good idea.
- You set Tag in one of the constructors, but I don't see it being used anywhere.

Comment: thank for the suggestions. Some answers to your questions:

Comment: I am very well aware of the non deterministic nature of Abort(). It should not be used anyway too often. Aborting a threadPool thread is ok in my tests as the thread gets recycled and started again for a new execution just fine.  The only difficulty is making sure you abort it while it's running your task and not some other thing scheduled by the pool. I am trying to be sure of that with the locks on _abortLock in the finally clause of the delegate and the Abort method

Comment: on your specific case i think i need to add an lock(_abortLock) to run in addition to the present _completedLock. That should take care of this scenarion

Comment: the Tag property is there so i can mark a task with some identifier and be able to differentiate it from other similar tasks in the same collection.

Comment: @AZ01, It might be better to just use the one lock object for both "_completedLock" and "_abortLock" (and just give it a more generic name). Regarding the Tag, I had thought it was intended for use by the inner thread but saw no easy way for the inner thread to access it. If its for the organization of the tasks then it should be fine.

Comment: one single lock object would cause problems with a long running task that has a WaitForCompletion on it. The wait call will acquire the lock and it would block any Abort calls that might be needed. That's why i have a separate lock for abort and another for completion. As no one else has posted a better analysis on this question i will mark yours as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/aa1dd834-3c3d-409b-907e-196ee8f427bf) helps you:

> If you download Reactive Extensions for .NET 3.5SP1 from  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx, you'll find a System.Threading.dll assembly... that contains TPL for .NET 3.5.

PS: The Rx page has moved to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609